# Incompatible types: List<Movie> cannot be converted to List<Item>

Tags: android, retrofit, incompatibletypeerror

I'm building an application to test **Retrofit** and `CardView`, `RecyclerView` and `Glide`. I have this object 'Item' where I define the attributes of a movie:

```
public class Item {
    @SerializedName("poster_path")
    private String posterPath;
    @SerializedName("adult")
    private boolean adult;
    @SerializedName("overview")
    private String overview;
    @SerializedName("release_date")
    private String releaseDate;
    @SerializedName("genre_ids")
    private List<Integer> genreIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    @SerializedName("id")
    private Integer id;
    @SerializedName("original_title")
    private String originalTitle;
    @SerializedName("original_language")
    private String originalLanguage;
    @SerializedName("title")
    private String title;
    @SerializedName("backdrop_path")
    private String backdropPath;
    @SerializedName("popularity")
    private Double popularity;
    @SerializedName("vote_count")
    private Integer voteCount;
    @SerializedName("video")
    private Boolean video;
    @SerializedName("vote_average")
    private Double voteAverage;

    public Item(String posterPath, boolean adult, String overview, String releaseDate, List<Integer> genreIds, Integer id,
                     String originalTitle, String originalLanguage, String title, String backdropPath, Double popularity,
                     Integer voteCount, Boolean video, Double voteAverage) {
        this.posterPath = posterPath;
        this.adult = adult;
        this.overview = overview;
        this.releaseDate = releaseDate;
        this.genreIds = genreIds;
        this.id = id;
        this.originalTitle = originalTitle;
        this.originalLanguage = originalLanguage;
        this.title = title;
        this.backdropPath = backdropPath;
        this.popularity = popularity;
        this.voteCount = voteCount;
        this.video = video;
        this.voteAverage = voteAverage;
    }

    public String getPosterPath() {
        return posterPath;
    }

    public void setPosterPath(String posterPath) {
        this.posterPath = posterPath;
    }

    public boolean isAdult() {
        return adult;
    }

    public void setAdult(boolean adult) {
        this.adult = adult;
    }

    public String getOverview() {
        return overview;
    }

    public void setOverview(String overview) {
        this.overview = overview;
    }

    public String getReleaseDate() {
        return releaseDate;
    }

    public void setReleaseDate(String releaseDate) {
        this.releaseDate = releaseDate;
    }

    public List<Integer> getGenreIds() {
        return genreIds;
    }

    public void setGenreIds(List<Integer> genreIds) {
        this.genreIds = genreIds;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getOriginalTitle() {
        return originalTitle;
    }

    public void setOriginalTitle(String originalTitle) {
        this.originalTitle = originalTitle;
    }

    public String getOriginalLanguage() {
        return originalLanguage;
    }

    public void setOriginalLanguage(String originalLanguage) {
        this.originalLanguage = originalLanguage;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getBackdropPath() {
        return backdropPath;
    }

    public void setBackdropPath(String backdropPath) {
        this.backdropPath = backdropPath;
    }

    public Double getPopularity() {
        return popularity;
    }

    public void setPopularity(Double popularity) {
        this.popularity = popularity;
    }

    public Integer getVoteCount() {
        return voteCount;
    }

    public void setVoteCount(Integer voteCount) {
        this.voteCount = voteCount;
    }

    public Boolean getVideo() {
        return video;
    }

    public void setVideo(Boolean video) {
        this.video = video;
    }

    public Double getVoteAverage() {
        return voteAverage;
    }

    public void setVoteAverage(Double voteAverage) {
        this.voteAverage = voteAverage;
    }
}
```

And inside MainActivity I declare this List of items:

```
private List<Item> movies;
```

Later inside the `onCreate` method I call this method to request some data from the imdb API:

```
ApiInterface apiService =
                ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

        Call<MoviesResponse> call = apiService.getTopRatedMovies(API_KEY);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<MoviesResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<MoviesResponse> call, Response<MoviesResponse> response) {
                int statusCode = response.code();
                movies = response.body().getResults();
                //recyclerView.setAdapter(new MoviesAdapter(movies, R.layout.list_item_movie, context));

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<MoviesResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                // Log error here since request failed
                Log.e(TAG, t.toString());
            }
        });
```

I am trying to insert all the data from the API inside the 'movies' List, but the problem is that I am getting an error that says that this 'movies' List comes from `android.graphics.Movie` instead of my class Item. And I don't know why. How can I fix this?

Edit:

Error message

```
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

Configuration 'compile' in project ':app' is deprecated. Use 'implementation' instead.
:app:buildInfoDebugLoader
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:splitsDiscoveryTaskDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources
:app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
/Users/Mvaguimaraes/Documents/Android Projects/MusicAppCardView/app/src/main/java/com/example/mvaguimaraes/musicappcardview/MainActivity.java:86: error: incompatible types: List<Movie> cannot be converted to List<Item>
                movies = response.body().getResults();
                                                   ^
1 error

 FAILED
:app:buildInfoGeneratorDebug

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 17s

15 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 12 up-to-date
```

Comment: Please attach your logcat if possible

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The project doesn't get to build to show the error in the logcat, but I updated the question with the expanded error message from the Gradle console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That means that you've imported the wrong Movie class somewhere.

Check your Retrofit Services if you included an import for

```
import android.graphics.Movie;
```

somewhere instead your own Model.

Doublecheck your Retrofit Service **ApiInterface** if you've List or only a generic List as return value instead of

```
List<Item>
```

That means make sure it's something like

```
@GET("your/path")
Call<List<Item>> listItems();
```

instead of

```
@GET("your/path")
Call<List> listItems();
```

or

```
@GET("your/path")
Call<List<Movie>> listItems();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, Apparently AndroidStudio automatically imported the android.graphics.Movie in the MovieResponse class instead of my Item class (which was previously called Movie).

Comment: Common issue ;-) Will happen often in your time as developer. Trust me in this case ;)

Comment: Thank you very much! I am still getting used to Android Development XD